# Blackberry Phonegap load device showing error

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I am developing the `blackberry phonegap application`. I have set all environment required to build the application. I am using command prompt to debug the application when i build the application it build successfully. But while loading the device it causing error as follows.

```
C:\bbtest>ant blackberry load-device
Buildfile: C:\bbtest\build.xml

blackberry:

load-device:

generate-cod-name:
     [echo] Generated name: cordovaExample.cod

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\bbtest\build

package-app:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\bbtest\build\widget
     [copy] Copying 24 files to C:\bbtest\build\widget
      [zip] Building zip: C:\bbtest\build\cordovaExample.zip

load-device:
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing command line options
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing bbwp.properties
     [exec] [INFO]                      Validating application archive
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing config.xml
     [exec] [INFO]                      Populating application source
     [exec] [INFO]                      Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks applicatio
n
     [exec] [INFO]                      Starting signing tool
     [exec] [INFO]                      Signing complete
     [exec] [INFO]                      Generating output files
     [exec] [INFO]                      BlackBerry WebWorks application packagin
g complete
     [exec] RIM Wireless Handheld Java Loader
     [exec] Copyright 2001-2009 Research In Motion Limited
     [exec] Connecting to device...debug: HRESULT error during Open: 80040154
     [exec] Error: unable to open port

BUILD FAILED
C:\bbtest\build.xml:49: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\bbtest\blackberry.xml:53: exec returned: 3

Total time: 53 seconds

C:\bbtest>
```

Any Idea why this is happing any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to nail down the problem with that information but I suspect you have a problem with "**target name**" in your xml.

Make sure the load-device is correctly targeted in your blackberry.xml as shown.

```
<target name="load-device" depends="package-app">
        <bbwp code-sign="true" />
        <exec executable="${javaloader}" dir="." failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-u" />
            <arg value="-w${properties.blackberry.sim.password}" />
            <arg value="load" />
            <arg file="${build.dir}/StandardInstall/${cod.name}.cod" />
        </exec>
    </target>
```

Also make sure that your directories are properly set in project.properties.

```
blackberry.bbwp.dir=C:\\TheBlackBerryWebWorksSDK
blackberry.sim.dir=C:\\TheEclipseBlackBerry\\plugins\\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\\components\\simulator
blackberry.mds.dir=C:\\TheBlackBerryWebWorksSDK\\mds
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may not have BlackBerry Desktop Manager installed. You can download this from http://uk.blackberry.com/software/desktop/desktop-pc.html

Answer (score 0):

This error is also thrown when using the incorrect deployment command.
In my case I tried to deploy my application to a BB10 device using *ant blackberry load-device* instead of *ant qnx load-device.*

Here's a snippet from the documentation:

BlackBerry 10 (QNX) - ant qnx load-device

BlackBerry PlayBook - ant playbook load-device

BlackBerry Smartphone (OS5-7) - ant blackberry load-device

See http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html